# Related Rates Problem? Please help!

Tags: calculus

So the problem goes: A small helium balloon is rising at a constant rate of 3 ft/sec, a horizontal distance of 16 feet from a 20ft. lamppost. At what rate is the shadow of the balloon moving along the ground when the balloon is 6 feet above the ground?
I am confused as to how to start this problem. I know I have to use properties of similar triangles.

Comment: Do you know the correct answer? I come up with 4.9ft/sec. I can post what I did if you would like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a picture of what we want to start with (if we rotated this image $90^\circ$):
$:       
         / |
        /a|
       /   | 
      /    |
     /     |x
    /__|     
   /  h  |
  /       | 
 /        | 16
/___ |
    20
$
Where $a$ is the angle of elevation of our triangle and $h$ is the height of the balloon.  We're given $\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{3ft}{sec}$.  Note that using the smaller triangle, $tan(a) = \frac{h}{x} \Leftrightarrow xtan(a) =h$.  Using the larger triangle, we have $tan(a) = \frac{20}{16+x}$.  Substituting that into the former equation gives $x\left(\frac{20}{x+16}\right) = h$.  Then, we take a derivative with respect to time on each side:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{20x}{x+16}\right) &= \frac{d}{dt} h \\
\frac{(x+16)20x' - (20x)x'}{(x+16)^2} &= \frac{dh}{dt} \\
\frac{320x'}{(x+16)^2} &= \frac{dh}{dt} \\
\end{align*}

Then, $x' = \frac{(x+16)^2}{320}\frac{dh}{dt} = \frac{3(x+16)^2}{320}$.

Using similar triangles to find $x$ given $h=6$, $\frac{x}{6} = \frac{x+16}{20}$ so that $x = \frac{47}{7}$.  Hence, plugging this value in yields $x' = \frac{4.898ft}{sec}$.